# Xdebug can't bind to port in Atom

Tags: php, virtualbox, xdebug, atom-editor

At long last, I'm trying to learn how to use xdebug, and of course, stuck from the start. Xdebug was already installed on my PHP, so no worries there, and following the instructions in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862137/debug-php-in-atom-while-using-vagrant), I setup my IDE (Atom) to connect to xdebug, with the only difference being I left the port at the default port 9000 and my IP being different.

Unfortunately, when I try to hit the debug button, I get the following error:

```
Could not bind socket, do you already have an instance of the debugger open?
```

I don't have another instance of the debugger open, as far as I know.

The biggest difference I can think of is that I am running a VM I setup myself while the guide uses Vagrant (I did not know how easy Vagrant was to setup until a bit ago). One thing that may make a difference but I'm not sure is that I'm setting the `PathMaps` through the settings config made available through project-manager package. I've done other settings through it, so don't think that should make a difference?

I'm trying to learn more about servers but unfortunately still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is related to a bug in the Atom plugin to use Xdebug, though even with the workaround people have suggested, I can't seem to get it working, so not sure if I've done something wrong a la my question above or if the bug is at fault :/